# Why my https site url is striked red though I have configured and made it secure

Tags: html, security, ssl, https, payment-gateway

I have bought comodo certificate for my site to have https link and has 128bit ssl encryption.But it still says my site is not secure.When I checked the ssl verifcation of my site,it says everything is secure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnVH9.png

this is how it shows. Is it because my site have external links to http ? Or what are all the mandatory things to be done in my webpage to have the https in green and have full secure identification ? Why does it says that my page has "Other resources which are not secure,these resources can be viewed by others in transit and can be modified by an attacker to change the behaviour of the page?
what can be this "other resources" which are not secure??

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong. You are loading content over an insecure connection. Check your javascript files, css, and images and make sure they are also loaded over HTTPS

Comment: I have the css and javascripts from my  server itself.So I have give the links "./example.js" or "./example.css" ..This can be a problem? Should that particular page have all https link,or https links in all pages of my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are making cross-protocol requests. You likely have embedded content with http, such as `<img src="http://mydomain.com/myimage.jpg">`, if that is the case, let the browser resolve the protocol for you by change the requests to `<img src="//mydomain.com/myimage.jpg">`. Doing that will allow the current page protocol to be used when resolving the document. Note, it might not be your content, you might have other embedded content such as analytics, but in general, you cannot mix protocols when in https.

Comment: So whats the solution? change all the external links like //mydomain.com/myimage.jpg ? And will have to change this in all pages for my website or just the page which need to show https?

Comment: Just the page(s) with https.

Comment: If you change it for the pages without https it won't affect it negatively though.